# Angular ui grid tooltip not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am having a problem to display header `tooltip` on `angular-ui-grid`.
Here is [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0UsQsSlIXBD6zkjyWX6?p=preview).

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: API says headerTooltip is a boolean, but their example says it's the string you want to show. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef vs http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/117_tooltips - so yes, good question!

Comment: I was able to patch it for now using my solution below, Hopefully it will help for now.

Comment: I fixed the Plunker link sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to figure out how to make the directive work properly internally by setting the headerTooltips as strings. The directive developers are making it work using a different implementation than yours that can be seen in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzoWBCHQkvozNXSxIHEh?p=preview).

This solution will patch the problem until a better or more permanent one can be found. Place it at the end of your service call inside of your controller like the following.

```
upareneStavkePromise.then(function(upareneStavkeData){
            $log.debug(upareneStavkeData);
            $scope.ucitaniUpareniPodaci = true;
            $scope.gridOptionsUpareniPodaci.data = upareneStavkeData.grupe;
            upareneStavkeTotals = upareneStavkeData.totals;


             /*
              * Patch for possible bug:
              * Description: Setting headerTooltip property
              * value as a string doesn't render the value at
              * runtime.
              *   
              */ 

            //class for the header span element
            var headerClass = ".ui-grid-header-cell-primary-focus";

            //the column definitions that were set by the developer
            var colDefs = $scope.gridOptionsUpareniPodaci.columnDefs;

            //Get the NodeList of the headerClass elements.
            //It will be an array like structure.
            var headers = document.querySelectorAll(headerClass);    

                //loop through the headers
                angular.forEach(headers,function(value,key){//begin forEach

                    //Set the title atribute of the headerClass element to
                    //the value of the headerTooltip property set in the columnDefs
                    //array of objects.
                    headers[key].title = colDefs[key].headerTooltip;                    


                });//end forEach


            /****************END PATCH********************/          


        });
```

Comment: I will check it. Meanwhile your plunker link is link to  empty plunk.